# How to get video playback in Birth of the Federation under recent Windows version?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, windows, star-trek-birth-of-the-federation

I managed to install "Star Trek: Birth of Federation" (BotF) on Window7x64 on the default path `C:\botf`.

I can start the game with compatible mode set to "Windows XP SP3".

Unfortunately, the intro video and galactic power intro video aren't rendered properly within the game.

How can I get BotF to play the videos under Window7?

My use case is Windows7 specifically, though I do not mind answers aiming at other recent Window versions.

Comment: Maybe it will help to install the last version of some codecks pack (ex.: https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)

Comment: @AlexChermenin Will try that, though can you may expand on which specific codec I may be missing? I like to only make minimal changes to my system in order to get the game up and running instead of a shotgun approach.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I noticed when trying to play botf.

- Always run as administrator
- Always run Windows XP SP3 compatibility
- Check your monitor settings. Disable Gsync or Freesync if you have an applicable monitor. Disabling Gsync and freesync seems to have fixed nearly every old game issue that I have. Good luck.

Comment: Does this solve the video problems that the OP was experiencing?